# Django template img src not working

Tags: django, image, src

I want to print an image by using a img src tag in a Django template file "base.html":

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Foto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My helpful timestamp site</h1>
    <img src="google.png" / >
    <hr>
    <p>Made by ... </p>
</body>
</html>
```

In views.py I define:

```
def hello(request):
    return render_to_response('base.html')
```

But the image does not show up in the browser. If I open it as a simple html file, it shows up in the browser.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That happens because Django does not know the path to this image.
Make a folder named `static/`, and then a folder named `images/` in your project root(where your settings.py file resides).

```
my_project/
    my_project/ 
        settings.py
        static/
           images/
             google.png
```

And then change it to:

```
<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}images/google.png" / >
```

More [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#basic-usage).

Comment: Since I have only one image, I didn't want to use static files. I saw from the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/templates/builtins/ the example: <img src="bar.gif" height="10" width="{% widthratio this_value max_value 100 %}" />

Comment: This is just an example. The common way to go is the one that i described in my answer.

Answer (score 26):

In recent versions of *django*

`<img src="{% static 'path/to/image.ext' %}"/>`

Comment: `{% load static %}`
`<img src="{% static 'path/to/image.ext' %}"/>`
Worked for me, thanks a ton!

Comment: This saved my bacon! Thank you!

Comment: @WEshruth You should consider posting your comment as an answer. It answers the question definitively.

Comment: Please check that the path to image **inside** the static directory is correct, I spent hours before realizing this silly mistake

Comment: What if we have set image in preloader then? I have other images in same folder & they map correclty but except this one which i have placed as a preloader image. Please Help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

You have got to add load static tag in the beginning of your **Django** template, best luck with below code.

```
{% load static %} 
<img src="{% static 'path/to/image.ext' %}"/>
```