# Internet application uploaded on Heroku does not show any graphics

Tags: python, django, heroku

I uploaded the my whole application on heroku but I have a problem does not display any photos. The path to the pictures is defined in this way:

```
src="{{blog.image.url}}"
```

Therefore, the view should not only be local (I think so).

After uploading the application, my view of django.admin it also looks strange.[image]

Any help will be appreciated! How can I solve this ( to be pictures will be displayed)? Can I do it without re-uploading the application (my database is completed)?

Comment: You’ll need to review and be sure your app is configured via these great instructions https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets. Fortunately it’s relatively easy.

Comment: Whether to display these files I need for example Amazon S3 or something like that?

Comment: This explains using aws s3 to host your static assets if thats what you are looking to do https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3, let me know if you have difficulty achieving this once you first are sure your app is serving static files via the first link I mentioned and this part is confusing for you.

Comment: I'll also refer you to these 3 links to check each part of your code base: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360395/display-images-in-django, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481172/django-template-img-src-not-working, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902890/django-image-src-not-found. hope that is all helpful and gets you working.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! everything works !

Answer (score 1):

If someone meet the same problem:

**This provides support for files such as CSS in Heroku**

1.) In file settings.py just add the following code:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

*Important links at this stage:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets*

**Provides multimedia showing**

2.) In settings.py would add:

```
#<-------------Elements Amazon S3 Beginning --------->

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'reviews/static'),
] #ok

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'YYY'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXX'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'name'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

#AWS_LOCATION = 'static' #ok
#STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage' #OK
#STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION) # już wystęuje

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'winerama.storage_backends.MediaStorage'  # <-- here is where we reference it

#<-------------Elements Amazon S3 END -------------->
```

2.1) In the same folder add a file storage_backends.py

```
#FIle for amazon 3s
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False
```

*of course, we also have to create amazon 3s account.

*Important links at this stage:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html (very good tutorial how to use amazon 3s to media files and static files)*

2.2)I also use these commands when adding an application to Heroku:

```
heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=YYY
heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=s'name'
```

*Important links at this stage:*
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

3.) In deploy it helped me
https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/heroku/
(I think the link is helpful but to deploy the whole application help me the following answer in the forum)

> 1. disable the collectstatic during a deploy
>
>    `heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`
> 2. deploy
>
>    `git push heroku master`
> 3. run migrations (django 1.10 added at least one)
>
>    `heroku run python manage.py migrate`
> 4. run collectstatic using bower
>
>    `heroku run 'bower install --config.interactive=false;grunt prep;python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'`
> 5. enable collecstatic for future deploys
>
>    `heroku config:unset DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC`
> 6. try it on your own (optional)
>
>    `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic`

Author of the statement **tomcounsell**
Link: [Collectstatic error while deploying Django app to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665889/collectstatic-error-while-deploying-django-app-to-heroku)

Please forgive my bad English.